# Register event on class items and get its attribute on click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to open a menu on right click on any of class items.

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu")
function contextMenu(e, atr) {
    //some code
}
var document_item = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for (var i = 0; i < document_item.length; i++) {
     var atr = document_item[i].getAttribute("inspect")
     document_item[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {contextMenu(e, atr) })
}
```

Every event is called with the same atr value (the last loaded)

So the atr should be attribute of clicked div with class item

Comment: check in the event var `e` - there is usually something like `e.currentTarget`

Answer (score 1):

If you do like you do, the function attached to the event listener will always have the current value the var has, because the loop is already ended when the event fires, it will be the last value. You can "save" the value using an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Execution) with a parameter:

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu")
function contextMenu(e, atr) {
    //some code
}
var document_item = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for (var i = 0; i < document_item.length; i++) {
     var atr = document_item[i].getAttribute("inspect")
     document_item[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', (function(_atr){ return function (e) {contextMenu(e, _atr) }; })(atr) )
}
```

You can also get the value of your attribute in the function with `e.currentTarget`, as Pete commented

Comment: Thank you, but its easier with ```e.currentTarget``` So I don't have to create any other variable

Comment: @TomiKordos yeah of course ;) you can still remember this for future use, because it's a frequent solution with async behaviour in JS to keep a parameter value from loops

Answer (score 1):

You have it implicitly inside your event handler.

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
function contextMenu(e) {
     var atr = e.target.inspect; // or this.inspect and remove e parameter
     // go on here, 'atr' will be 'undefined' if the element has no attribute 'inspect'
}
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName("item"), 
    function (element) {
        element.addEventListener('contextmenu', contextMenu, false);
    }
);
```